# PHP not showing anything in browser

Tags: php

I don't know if it's my code or what, but echo is not showing anything.

```
<?php
function outside() {
    $GLOBALS['variable'] = 'some value';
    inside();
}

function inside() {
        global $variable;
        echo $variable;
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you calling outside() function?

Comment: Umm, do you ever call either of those functions?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just because it's an easy answer does not mean it's a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only defining the functions here. You never actually execute either of them. Try adding:

```
outside();
```

after the function definitions.

See it in action here: https://eval.in/79203